# DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm migrating my ticket-system to slash commands, but im getting an error when i click the create button from the embed, and i get `This interaction failed` (img below).

[image]

I do get this error apon clicking on the button

```
/rbd/pnpm-volume/bfd39791-83e8-4795-a0ba-c6440c330833/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:293
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/rbd/pnpm-volume/bfd39791-83e8-4795-a0ba-c6440c330833/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/rbd/pnpm-volume/bfd39791-83e8-4795-a0ba-c6440c330833/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (/rbd/pnpm-volume/bfd39791-83e8-4795-a0ba-c6440c330833/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferReply (/rbd/pnpm-volume/bfd39791-83e8-4795-a0ba-c6440c330833/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:68:5)
at async /app/events/interaction/ticketSystem.js:239:17 {
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1019616146007277618/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAxOTYxNjE0NjAwNzI3NzYxODpaSGRYOTVDdjFhc1RNdkhWNjlPempxcUFjV2hHdm94WE9tVVBmVUlMeUY2R2dxb25NTGtWZ3hlTkl4czhqeWR6WG9XUEZ6U09pa3I2VE52OVBzcXJVQndvSlZGMkx4ODQ2UWpreG5ncklKeW5EYU1SN2hqQXdQTVh1ZVRvOGRMZg/callback',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 5, data: { flags: undefined } } }
}
```

interactionCreate

```
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonInteraction, ButtonStyle, ChannelType, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../../index");
const supportSchema = require("../../models/ticket/supportRole");
const categorySchema = require("../../models/ticket/category");
const wait = require('node:timers/promises').setTimeout;

module.exports = {
  name: "interactionCreate",
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    try {
      if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "tic") {
          let ticketChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((tc) => tc.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`);
          let ticketCategory = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === "tickets");
          
          if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`)) return interaction.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> You currently have an open ticket.\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${ticketChannel.id}>`, ephemeral: true });
          if (!interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels)) return interaction.reply({ content: "I do not have perms to create your ticket channel. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`", ephemeral: true });
          
          if (interaction.guild.channels.cache.some((type) => type.type === ChannelType.GuildCategory && type.name === "tickets")) {
            console.log(`A new ticket has been created in ${interaction.guild.name} by ${interaction.user.username}`);
            //await interaction.reply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!`, ephemeral: true }).catch(err => {});
          } else {
            categorySchema.findOne({ Guild: interaction.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
                if (data) {
                  const ticketCategory = interaction.guild.channels.create({
                      name: `${data.Category}`,
                      permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                          id: interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest,
                          allow: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          id: interaction.user.id,
                          allow: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                          deny: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                      type: ChannelType.GuildCategory,
                    })
                    .catch();
                }

                if (!data) {
                  const ticketCategory = interaction.guild.channels
                    .create({
                      name: "tickets",
                      permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                          id: interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest,
                          allow: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          id: interaction.user.id,
                          allow: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                          deny: [
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                            PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                      type: ChannelType.GuildCategory,
                    })
                    .catch();
                }
              }
            );
          }

          supportSchema.findOne({ Guild: interaction.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
              if (data) {
                let role = data.Role;
                const channel = await interaction.guild.channels
                  .create({
                    name: `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`,
                    parent: ticketCategory,
                    topic: "Ticketing made easy, right at your fingertips!",
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                      {
                        id: interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest,
                        allow: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        id: interaction.user.id,
                        allow: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                        deny: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        id: role,
                        allow: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                  })
                  .catch();
                
                let ticketEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .setTitle("__Support Ticket__")
                  .setDescription("> Support will be with you shortly. While you wait, please let us know how we can help you today!\n\nClick on the ️ to close this ticket")
                  .setColor("Green")
                  .setFooter({ text: `User ID: ${interaction.user.id}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                  .setTimestamp();

                let deleteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId("delChannelWithData")
                  .setLabel("️ Close")
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                  .setDisabled(false);
                
                await interaction.deferReply();
                await wait(7000);
                await interaction.editReply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${channel.id}>`, ephemeral: true }).catch(err => {});
                channel.send({ content: `<@&${role}> <@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [ticketEmbed], components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(deleteButton)] });
                
                const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((lc) => lc.name === "mod-log");
                if (logchannel) {
                  const ticketLogs = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle("Ticket Created")
                    .addFields([
                      {
                        name: "Ticket Name",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${channel.name}\``,
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Opened by",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${interaction.user.tag}\``,
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Created",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <t:${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}:R>`,
                      },
                    ])
                    .setFooter({ text: "Crimson - Ticket Logger", iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                    .setColor("#5865F2")
                    .setTimestamp();
                  await logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
                }
              }

              if (!data) {
                const channel = await interaction.guild.channels
                  .create({
                    name: `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`,
                    parent: ticketCategory,
                    topic: "Ticketing made easy, right at your fingertips!",
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                      {
                        id: interaction.guild.members.me.roles.highest,
                        allow: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        id: interaction.user.id,
                        allow: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                        deny: [
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel,
                          PermissionsBitField.Flags.AttachFiles,
                        ],
                      },
                    ],
                    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                  })
                  .catch();

                let ticketEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                  .setTitle("__Support Ticket__")
                  .setDescription("> Support will be with you shortly. While you wait, please let us know how we can help you today!\n\nClick on the ️ to close this ticket")
                  .setColor("Green")
                  .setFooter({ text: `User ID: ${interaction.user.id}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                  .setTimestamp();

                let deleteButton = new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId("delChannelWithData")
                  .setLabel("️ Close")
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
                  .setDisabled(false);
                
                await interaction.deferReply();
                await wait(7000);
                await interaction.editReply({ content: `<:CL_Support:912055272275599380> Your ticket has been created!\n<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <#${channel.id}>`, ephemeral: true }).catch(err => {});
                channel.send({ content: `@here <@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [ticketEmbed], components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(deleteButton)] });

                const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find((lc) => lc.name === "mod-log");
                if (logchannel) {
                  const ticketLogs = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setTitle("Ticket Created")
                    .addFields([
                      {
                        name: "Ticket Name",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${channel.name}\``,
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Opened by",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${interaction.user.tag}\``,
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Created",
                        value: `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <t:${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}:R>`,
                      },
                    ])
                    .setFooter({ text: "Crimson - Ticket Logger", iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                    .setColor("#5865F2")
                    .setTimestamp();
                  await logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
                }
              }
            }
          );
        }

        if (interaction.customId === "delChannelWithData") {
          if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels)) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "You do not have perms to close this ticket. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`", ephemeral: true });
          } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "Closing ticket, please wait...", ephemeral: true }).then((ch) => {
                setTimeout(() => interaction.channel.delete(), 3000);
            }).catch((err) => interaction.reply(`\`${err}\``));
          }
        }

        if (interaction.customId === "delChannelWithoutData") {
          if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels)) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "You do not have perms to close this ticket. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`", ephemeral: true });
          } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "Closing ticket, please wait...", ephemeral: true }).then((ch) => {
                setTimeout(() => interaction.channel.delete(), 3000);
              }).catch((err) => interaction.reply(`\`${err}\``));
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      interaction.reply(`\`${err}\``);
    }
  },
};
```

i have tired to await the message before sending it to the user when they click it, because it does take a few extra seconds apart from clicking the button before it tries to send the message, but it fails..

the ticket channel is still being created even though the message is not being sent when clicking the button, and it sends the embed to the channel with no problem.

Comment: What's custom id of a button?

Comment: the custom id is **tic** `.setCustomId("tic")`

Comment: Try to deffer reply

Comment: it still throws an unknown interaction error, i have a feeling this is because its a slash command, because when i did this with the static version.. i did not have this issue.